# How to get funded to attend an international conference?

Tags: publications, funding, conference, international-students

I am from a developing country and I can not afford plane tickets or hotel accommodation fees all by myself, I am not funded by any organization and I am a fresh grad so not even my university can fund me.. I submitted for international conference and my paper got accepted, is there any way to get funded through any organization or through the conference itself? can I even get a discount? (it's a dental conference)

Comment: It depends on the conference, there is no general answer. But generally, there might be a few hundred dollars available, not thousands.

Comment: Try crowdfunding websites such as https://www.gofundme.com/

Comment: In computer science, some conferences and research organizations offer travel grants. Maybe you could check if there's something similar in your field.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes.  Although we can't help the OPs specifically, it is useful information that there exist grants one can apply for.

Comment: gofundme.com is apparently available only for some western countries! My country is not even there

Answer (score 1):

You can always try and ask the conference organizers for financial support, but it is not clear of it will work or not. Some organizations will also have travel grants to give out (e.g. [this one for biologists](https://www.biologists.com/grants/dmm-conference-travel-grants/)), so you might want to search the web for similar organizations in your field.

If you cannot find funding, another way to go is to see if it is possible to present your research without being present at the conference: either as a video presentation (if the conference allows such hybrid models) or as a poster presentation instead. Both options might not be as satisfactory as being there yourself, but at least you will have had the chance to show what you have worked on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slim chance that the following might be helpful, but just in case it is...

Some large conferences in CS and perhaps other fields have a need for "student volunteers" to help manage the conference as it proceeds. They carry messages, sit at registration desks, or whatever might be needed. Such positions come with free attendance at the conference (in my experience) and might (might) come with some travel stipend.

I'd guess that most such "students" are local, not requiring funding beyond attendance, but you can explore what might be available. And, how strictly they might define "student" is another question, but asking is free.